# Openpyxl - 'MergedCell' object attribute 'value' is read-only

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

If I do it the commented way, it works great.

But to clean up the code a little bit, I made a function to do it.

But if I try do it the function way,

I get `Openpyxl -  'MergedCell'` object attribute 'value' is read-only:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/vitor.augusto/Desktop/projeto_robozinho/robot_api/excel.py", line 67, in <module>
    preenche_linha(nr_solicitacao, 'D', start+1, 'center', 'total', ws)
  File "c:\Users\vitor.augusto\Desktop\projeto_robozinho\robot_api\functions\utils.py", line 31, in preenche_linha
    ws[f'{coluna}{linha}'] = valor
AttributeError: 'MergedCell' object attribute 'value' is read-only"
```

[image]

Comment: Please always provide code as text and not images.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to compare the two code snippets just postulate on what the error could be. 
It would seem likely that the cell referenced by **ws[f'{column}{row}']** is part of a merged cell set but is not the top left cell so cannot be written to.
E.g. I merge cells A1, B1, and C1 in a sheet. Cell A1 is the top left cell and is now that merged cell coordinate, B1 and C1 effectively no longer exist. If I attempted to enter a value into either B1 or C1

```
column = 2
row = 1
ws[f'{column}{row}'] = value
```

it would result in the **AttributeError: 'MergedCell' object attribute 'value' is read-only** error.
Check your code values for column and row being passed to the function when the error occurs.